# How can i use string interpolation with Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, interpolation

I have a Jekyll 3 project that allows language selection. We use the 'jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin' gem for internationalization.
We have a glossary that is supposed to display German terms or English terms according to the selected language. I get the selected language using the variable `site.lang` provided by the 'jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin' gem.
Right now glossary.html looks like this

```
  <div id="glossary">
    {% if site.lang == "de" %}
      {% for term in site.data['terms_de'] %}
        <!-- German glossary goes here -->
      {% endfor %}
    {% elsif site.lang == "en" %}
      {% for term in site.data['terms_en'] %}
        <!-- English glossary goes here -->
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
```

However, i'd love to have something like this

```
  <div id="glossary">
     {% for term in site.data["terms_#{site.lang}"] %}
       <!-- Glossary goes here -->
     {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

But for some reason, the string interpolation `"terms_#{site.lang}"` doesn't work. I also tried `'terms_'+site.lang`

I think the interpolation is not working because, when i put `{{ site.lang }}` in the page, i see the selected language, but when i write `{{ "terms_"+site.lang }}` i don't see anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `capture` tag, instead of displaying a value it sets to a variable:

```
{% capture term_lang %}{{ 'terms_' | append: site.lang }}{% endcapture%}
```

Then you can use that variable as the index of the array:

```
 site.data[term_lang]
```

In your example:

```
{% capture term_lang %}{{ 'terms_' | append: site.lang }}{% endcapture%}
<div id="glossary">
 {% for term in site.data[term_lang] %}
   <!-- Glossary goes here -->
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this solved my issue. There's is a little syntax error in your explanation though, you forgot to close `{{ 'terms_' | append: site.lang`

Comment: @JorgeJuniorArteagaCarvalho you are right, I've fixed it in the example!